# Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in /home/inrunitc/public_html/chek/chek.php on line 132

Tags: php, printf

```
Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in /home/inrunitc/public_html/chek/chek.php on line 132
Query was empty
```

I am new to PHP and mysql and I have like 88 fields in my form - what should I do ?

Comment: Posting code could help.

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling `sprintf()` on line 132. And passing it too few arguments

Comment: my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56208866/308578

Comment: what version of php and mysql?

Answer (score 4):

This happens if you have something like

```
$s = sprintf('%d %d %d', 4);
```

There are three placeholders in the [format string](http://docs.php.net/sprintf) but only one parameter.

Comment: what if you had this: $s = sprintf('%d %d', 4, 2, 1); Would this replace the two digit spaces and ignore the third supplied number (1) or throw an error.

Comment: @Ashley: No error/warning/notice message with the vanilla php.net 5.3.3 build, but there may be other (patched/hardened) builds that raise e.g. a notice.

Comment: my solutions according  to  my experiences : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56208866/308578