# Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm getting this PHP error in my custom breadcrumb function:

> Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /srv/bindings/56058a57d7424f84adac37ba6b03d3b7/code/wp-content/themes/inspire-spine/functions.php on line 151

Here is the code:

```
if ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
    if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
        $breadcrumbs = array();
        while ($parent_id) {
            $page = get_page($parent_id);
            if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID)); //, get_the_title($page->ID));
            }
            $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
        }
        $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
            echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
            if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $delimiter;
        }
    }
    if ($show_current == 1) {
        if ($show_home_link == 1 || ($parent_id_2 != 0 && $parent_id_2 != $frontpage_id)) echo $delimiter;
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    }

}
```

I get the error in line 7, what am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `$link`?

Comment: Here are all the variables:
 global $post;
    $home_link    = home_url('/');
    $link_before  = '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">';
    $link_after   = '</span>';
    $link_attr    = ' rel="v:url" property="v:title"';
    $link         = $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr . ' href="%1$s">%2$s</a>' . $link_after;
    $parent_id    = $parent_id_2 = $post->post_parent;
    $frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

Comment: Link to question edit function: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49098956/edit

Answer (score 2):

Your [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) string has 2 placeholders, you are filling only one.

```
<?php
// bad
echo sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'http://example.com');

// good
echo sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'http://example.com', 'Link Name');
```

https://3v4l.org/nu8Ht

Answer (score 0):

1. dont use **%** sign in your string when use **sprintf** method

in my case: for example:

```
$data = call_web_service(); // return array()
foreach ($data as $d)
echo sprintf("<div>our %65 discount is : %s </div>",
$d["discount"]
);
```

use %65 in my string

sprintf seek every % and if counts of them is not equal to your parameters return this error

2. dont use **< ?php** or **? >** in your string

like this :

```
$weekday = "sunday";
echo sprintf("<div>our <?php echo $date;?> day is : %s </div>",
$weekday
);
```