# Can you help me solve this? Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/kupinmvl/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 2668

Tags: php

Can some please help fix this code referred to the error. When I try to post a comment on some products on woocomerce.

here is the code:

```
$submit_button = sprintf(
            $args['submit_button'],
            esc_attr( $args['name_submit'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['class_submit'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] )
        );
```

Comment: What is the value of `$args['submit_button']`? Unless it contains a string with placeholders for replacements you are using `sprintf()` wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: sprintf() \[function.sprintf\]: Too few arguments in /home/inrunitc/public\_html/chek/chek.php on line 132](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760019/9193372)